# VB.net application first execution is too slow compared to the next ones

Tags: windows, vb.net

I'm working on a vb.net application that has heavy computing and I/O tasks ,the program's first execution after rebooting is too slow compared to the next execution times (10 seconds more to finish).I realized that at the first time the CPU usage reached about 60% and for the later executions it reached from 90% to 100% . Please does any one know why does that happen?

Comment: Gonna need a lot more information about what it does, code examples, etc. to be able to help with this.

Answer (score 1):

When you reboot your computer, it dumps everything stored in memory, along with the cache. The first time you run your program, VS has to pull your program and all the required assemblies and libraries from your hard drive for compilation, etc. After the first execution (and your question is quite vague so it's hard for me to acquire your current situation) VS keeps all that stuff in main memory until it's needed by other processes or you close VS.

Since main memory is much faster than primary storage, and since most of your external assemblies have been compiled into your program's build, subsequent executions will be faster.

The reason for CPU usage being much lower on the first run is because the data cannot be read from your hard drive fast enough to keep the CPU busy!

Comment: Thank you chris for your answer but let me explain to you how is everything working so that we can find a solution to the caching issue .im working on a large file about 2 GB so im using memorymappedfiles to read it twice cuz i cant fetch the whole file into memory . so do you think are there any ways to enhance the read operation in the second time ?